# How to exclude some changes before pushing my branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

In my current branch because of my mistakes, **two** sets of files are showing up.
Some of these files are for **ANOTHER** feature branch I am working on.
Some of these files are the **actual** files I need for this current branch that I am on.

So I want to commit and push my current branch but first how do I **exclude** those extra files from getting included?  I still **do** need them but for another branch.

Comment: lookup the use of `git stash`. It allows you to move changes aside, do some other changes and later recall the changes in the stash back to whatever branch you are working on.

Comment: @chegancasb  : Thanks, using Visual Studio I see a Stash All Include Untracked and also a Stash and Keep Staged. Do you know which one is that?

Comment: I am not familiar with Visual Studio. But I think that is address in the URL. https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/10/the-git-stash-functionality-in-visual-studio-2019/

It states that `Stash All` is to store the uncommited changes in the stash and revert those same changes in the current branch and `Stash and Keep Staged` will keep the changes in the current branch.

Comment: git add only those you need in this branch, commit, push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have modified `file1` and `file2`. you want to make a commit `correction for bug1` with `file1` and another commit `Correct bug2` with `file2`.

Either, you only stage `file1` and make your commit like this:

```
git add file1
git commit -m "Correction bug1"
```

and you can continue as if you still have `file2` modified and uncommitted.

Or you stash the file that you do not need (here `file2`) for the next commit by
and then you stage and commit the correct file.

```sh
git stash push file2
git add file1
git commit -m "Correction bug1"
```

After `git stash ...` , the file `file2` will be stashed and appear as it was before your modifications.

Later you may retrieve the stashed modifications for use.

```
git stash pop
```

will restore the modifications of `file2` as before the `git stash` command.

Comment: Thanks, using VS I see a Stash and also a Stash and Keep Staged.
Do you know which one is that?

Comment: Stash allows you to stash (save for later use) and stage allows you to add the file to be included in the next commit you will do